# In what TimeZone does SharePoint Online save DateTime dates

Tags: datetime, sharepoint-online

I have searched the web but haven't found answers to the question in which TimeZone does SharePoint save the DateTime objects in the database. When dates are returned to me with C# or PowerShell they are always one day off. My timezone is `W.Europe Standard Time`. (Stockholm, Sweden) How should I convert the returned date if I want to make a comparison to today's date?

> Update

I managed to build this piece of PowerShell code from your examples. But It cant find the TimeZone. What am I doing wrong?

`$strCurrentTimeZone = (Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName
$TZ = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($strCurrentTimeZone)//<--False to find TimeZoneById
$LocalTime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($SharePointTime, $TZ)`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.

I fixed this issue in CSOM (C#) with the following lines of code:

```
//Retrieve the date value from SP (1 day off in your case)
DateTime spDate = Convert.ToDateTime(spItem["DateField"]); 

//Retrieve the timezone from the SharePoint web
var spTimeZone = context.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
context.Load(spTimeZone);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//Get the System.TimeZoneInfo from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TimeZone
var fixedTimeZoneName = spTimeZone.Description.Replace("and", "&");
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Where(tz => tz.DisplayName == fixedTimeZoneName).FirstOrDefault();

//Setting the DateTimeKind to Unspecified (otherwise the last function could return an error)
spDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(spDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

//Getting destination timezone for the new Date
var europeanTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Where(t => t.Id == "W. Europe Standard Time").FirstOrDefault();

//Converting the DateTime to your 'W.Europe Standard Time' timezone
DateTime correctDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(spDate, timeZoneInfo.Id, europeanTimeZone.Id);
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it out first thing Monday. No computer for the whole weekend.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint stores datetime field values in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) format and convert it to appropriate time zone whenever it is retrieved by a user. However when using SharePoint API, the date returned is in UTC format and have to be converted to local time.

In *C#/PowerShell* datetime could be converted to local time via [`TimeZone.ToLocalTime` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
 var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
 var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
 ctx.Load(item);
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();

 var created = (DateTime)item["Created"];
 var createdLoc = System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(created);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it out first thing Monday. No computer the whole weekend.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @Vladim, In the end, I rebuilt my PowerShell into C#. Your suggestion works fine on my local machine. But when I put my C# code in an Azure TimeTrigger Function it won't convert the date from SharePoint to the correct local time. Have you come across this problem?